# Capturing images with blended images in nokia imaging sdk

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, nokia-imaging-sdk, lumia-imaging-sdk

I am  making windows phone app using nokia imaging sdk and example of app is this [real time blend demo](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/nokia-imaging-sdk/sample-projects/real-time-blend-demo.html)

I am trying to capture image with Image overlayed image i.e image with other image in top of it as in above example in live camera stream below is code i am trying to capture image with effect

```
        CameraCaptureSequence cameraCaptureSequence = App.Camera.CreateCaptureSequence(1);

        MemoryStream stream  = new MemoryStream();

        cameraCaptureSequence.Frames[0].CaptureStream = stream.AsOutputStream();

        await App.Camera.PrepareCaptureSequenceAsync(cameraCaptureSequence);
        await cameraCaptureSequence.StartCaptureAsync();

        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
        library.SavePictureToCameraRoll("picture1.jpg", stream);
```

but the above code only saves image without effect, so how to capture images with live blended effects from camera.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you have to do is attach the same effects/filters that you had in the preview to a new image source taking the captured photo stream instead. And probably use a different renderer too.

Either that or set up a duplicate set of filters for the capture. There are reasons to, you could e.g. configure lower quality effects in the preview to help performance.